# Binance api endpoint for fiat deposits from bank card?

Tags: binance

I didn't find a history of fiat deposits(from bank card),
Only crypto deposits here: https://prnt.sc/ttdwc2=)
For example in my bank account interface I found deposit on 12th of may, but can't find it here...

Anyone know may be there is **api endpoint** to look for it?
Didn't find anything here https://github.com/binance-us/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

**Once again:** I didn't find anything about fiat deposits in api and website interface. It looks weird that there is no such way to see fiat history of deposits from credit cards.
May be I am missing something?

Comment: Did you find something in the meantime?

Comment: Same question, I am looking for those as well and can't find it... `client.get_deposit_history()` returns only cryptos.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand for today there is no such an endpoint for 02.28.2021
if anything changes it would be great
Or may be not great cause of taxes

Answer (score 0):

This was annoying me for a while but it looks like Binance devs have added some functionality.

I have started to use the binance-connector python package. It just makes it easier to navigate the API (no need to hash your keys). You can find more info here:

https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-python

The code I used:

```
from binance.spot import Spot as Client
from datetime import datetime

# api_key and secret_key you get when you set up your API on Binance

spot_client = Client(api_key, secret_key)

currTime = round((time.time()*1000))
startTime = "01/01/2021"
beginTime = round(datetime.strptime(startTime, "%d/%m/%Y").timestamp()*1000)
params = {
      "beginTime": beginTime,
      "endTime": currTime
         }
# 0 = deposit, 1 = withdrawals
# if no beginTime and endTime specified will give last 30 days

spot_client.fiat_order_history(0, **params)
```

More info here:
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#fiat-endpoints

Comment: Does this work for US endpoint?